# Asp.Net C# database connection not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web-config, connection-string

I have this connection string in my `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLServerConnectionString"
         connectionString= "..."
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And this simple C# code to pull from the db:

```
dbAD.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Profile ORDER BY FullName ASC", dbConnect);
dbAD.Fill(dbRS, "Profile");

if (dbRS.Tables("Profile").Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow employee in dbRS.Tables("Profile").Rows)
    {
        Response.Write("Employee: " + Profile("FullName") + " " + Profile("Academy") + "<p>");
    }
}
```

However, I get an error:

> The name 'dbAD' does not exist in the current context

I take it I need to define `dbAD`, or a few other variables before hand, but I'd only be guessing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, how initialize you dbAD, dbConnect, dbRS?

Comment: Hello @Esperento57 - the above code is all I have I'm afraid.

Comment: I hope for you that the password is not the real password of your online database. Not very wise to post that info.

Comment: @steve many thanks Steve. Of course it has been changed for stack

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

i up:

```
        using System.Data;
        using System.Data.OleDb;
        using System.Web.Configuration;



        OleDbConnection oledbCnn=null;
        OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter = null;
        DataSet ds=null;

        string connetionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Profile ORDER BY FullName ASC";


        try
        {
            oledbCnn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
            oledbCnn.Open();

            oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oledbCnn);

            ds = new DataSet();
            oledbAdapter.Fill(ds, "Profile");

            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Profile"].Rows)
            {
                Response.Write("Employee: " + " " + row["FullName"].ToString() + " " + row["Academy"].ToString() + "<p>");
            }

            oledbCnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (oledbCnn != null) oledbCnn.Dispose();
            if (oledbAdapter != null) oledbAdapter.Dispose();
            if (ds != null) ds.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: @davidxc frankly, if you're talking to SQL Server, `SqlConnection` should be your preferred choice *anyway*; I suspect you should just remove any mention of SQLOLEDB from the connection string...

Comment: and add using System.Web.Configuration;   too

Comment: what rows number?

Comment: modify Response.Write("Employee: " + " " + row["FullName"].ToString() + " " + row["Academy

Comment: I have modify my code for indicate you then using   ;)

Comment: "Using" are good positionned on your file .cs ? (it must be up to the page). Put all your code page please.

Comment: @MarcGravell Hi Marc. Thanks for this, may I ask why SQLOLEDB should be removed? Thanks, David.

Comment: @davidxc because sqloledb is talking about the legacy oledb provider, useful for compatibility and interop, but unnecessary when you can use the ado.net provider (SqlConnection).

Comment: @Esperento57 oh, ok, I see. It now says however: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute and that it extends the correct base class. Thanks for all your help!